# better multiple replace with curly braces

Tags: bash, shell-script

for a single replace the curly brace works fine 
but i cant find a solution for multiple replace where is the trick ?
or its not possible
for multiple replace i use sed
and for single the curly braces method

```
#example vars
addons="WEBIF_LIVELOG WEBIF_JQUERY TOUCH WITH_SSL READ_SDT_CHARSETS WITH_DEBUG MODULE_MONITOR"
protocols="MODULE_hans MODULE_paul MODULE_klaus MODULE_franz"
readers="READER_foo READER_bar READER_foobar READER_barfoo"
card_readers="CARDREADER_type1 CARDREADER_type2 CARDREADER_type3"

_create_module_arrays(){
i=0;
for e in $(echo "$addons" | sed 's/WEBIF_//g;s/WITH_//g;s/MODULE_//g;s/HAVE_//g;s/_CHARSETS//g;);
do
<------>SHORT_ADDONS+=($e);
<------>SHORT_MODULENAMES+=($e);
done;
for e in ${protocols//MODULE_/};
do
<------>SHORT_PROTOCOLS+=($e);
<------>SHORT_MODULENAMES+=($e);
done;
for e in ${readers//READER_/};
do
<------>SHORT_READERS+=($e);
<------>SHORT_MODULENAMES+=($e);
done;
for e in ${card_readers//CARDREADER_/};
do
<------>SHORT_CARD_READERS+=($e);
<------>SHORT_MODULENAMES+=($e);
done;
for e in $addons $protocols $readers $card_readers;
do
<------>ALL_MODULES_LONG+=($e);
done;
for e in "${SHORT_MODULENAMES[@]}";
do
<------>INTERNAL_MODULES["$e"]="${ALL_MODULES_LONG[i]}";((i++));
done;
};
```

Comment: You're already using the form `${variable//pattern/replacement}`, which should replace all matches.  Please edit the question to show your input (ie. the contents of `$protocols`, `$readers` etc.), expected results, and actual results.

Comment: look @ line 3 for e in $(echo "$addons" | sed

Comment: The `protocols`, `readers` and `card_readers` variables aren't set on line 3 or anywhere else. We need to see their values to work out why `bash`'s pattern substitution isn't doing what you want.

Comment: i add vars in first post ... but is clear what i sed in the first for loop

Comment: Oh, I see - you want to use `bash` _instead_ of that `sed` command.  Is there a reason you can't use multiple steps with temporary variables, ie `ADD=${addons//WEBIF_/} ; ADD=${ADD//WITH_/} ; ...` ?

Comment: no i want to replace it with a nicer way sed does the work but i do it multiple times

Answer (score 2):

In bash, if you want to delete these patterns, you could use extended pattern matching:

```
# optional - save extglob state
$ shopt -q extglob && extglob_disabled=false || extglob_disabled=true

# enable extended pattern matching
$ shopt -s extglob

$ addons="WEBIF_LIVELOG WEBIF_JQUERY TOUCH WITH_SSL READ_SDT_CHARSETS WITH_DEBUG MODULE_MONITOR"
$ echo ${addons//@(WEBIF_|WITH_|MODULE_|HAVE_|_CHARSETS)}
LIVELOG JQUERY TOUCH SSL READ_SDT DEBUG MONITOR

# optional - restore extglob state
$ $extglob_disabled && shopt -u extglob
```